# How to replicate pandas rows

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like this:

```
  '#filename'   file_size   file_attributes  region_count   region_id    region_shape_attributes     region_attributes  digits  digit_length

  0030004489.jpg    25188   {}                          3            1  {"name":"rect","x":143,"y":86,"width":201,"height":38}  {"class_type":"Medium Box"} 33328   6
  0030004489.jpg    25188   {}                          3            0  {"name":"rect","x":143,"y":75,"width":200,"height":68}  {"class_type":"Big Box"}    33328   6
  0030004745.jpg    23632   {}                          3            2  {"name":"rect","x":140,"y":61,"width":174,"height":47}  {"class_type":"Small Box"}  7631    8
  0030004745.jpg    23632   {}                          3            1  {"name":"rect","x":84,"y":62,"width":268,"height":45}   {"class_type":"Medium Box"} 7631    8
  0030004745.jpg    23632   {}                          3            0  {"name":"rect","x":86,"y":37,"width":266,"height":91}   {"class_type":"Big Box"}    7631    8
  0030005942.jpg    24178   {}                          3            2  {"name":"rect","x":268,"y":66,"width":84,"height":35}   {"class_type":"Small Box"}  196     4
  0030005942.jpg    24178   {}                          3            1  {"name":"rect","x":189,"y":66,"width":176,"height":35}  {"class_type":"Medium Box"} 196     4
  0030005942.jpg    24178   {}                          3            0  {"name":"rect","x":191,"y":48,"width":175,"height":64}  {"class_type":"Big Box"}    196     4
  0030012268.jpg    25450   {}                          3            2  {"name":"rect","x":218,"y":46,"width":113,"height":35}  {"class_type":"Small Box"}  369     6
  0030012268.jpg    25450   {}                          3            1  {"name":"rect","x":173,"y":46,"width":174,"height":35}  {"class_type":"Medium Box"} 369     6
  0030012268.jpg    25450   {}                          3            0  {"name":"rect","x":174,"y":35,"width":173,"height":45}  {"class_type":"Big Box"}    369     6
```

How do I replicate rows with class type small box and change append A_ to file name of the replicated row? I tried replicating rows like this:

```
    for f in file_name:
        df=df.append((df.loc[(df['#filename']) == (str(f).replace("A_",""))].iloc[0]*100))
        df.to_csv("test.csv")
        break
```

But the problem is that it appends all replicated rows to one cell like this :
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by `change append A_`?

Comment: For instance if file name is 0030012268.jpg then the replicated row will have file name A_0030012268.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df = #your Dtaframe

df2 = df[(df['digit_length']) == '{"class_type":"Small Box"}']
df2['#filename'] = df2['#filename'].apply(lambda x:"A_"+x)

replicated_df = pd.concat([df,df2])
```

Comment: When I save it to csv, there are no newly generated/replicated rows

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can do using [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
n_rows = 100
for f in file_name:

    # sample data or replicate rows
    f=df[df['#filename'] == f].sample(n_rows, replace=True)
    f['#filename'] = 'A_' + f['#filename']

    # concat data back to the original df
    df = pd.concat([df, f], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This one is working fine. But the problem is that for files it is replicating rows from either : small, big, medium box. While on the other hand I expect it to replicate row for all classes

Comment: I don't think that should happen since we are doing `.sample` on the entire dataframe. Could you show few rows where this is happening ? May be add it in the question.